# Octave / CLI -- Keeping long outputs on the same console line

Tags: io, command-line-interface, octave

I'm using algorithms that require some time to compute and if I print an output to be sure that the correct section of code is executing even writing a single `.` per iteration I end up with entire screens full of dots that cover up all previous outputs that I might have been interest in.

**Is there a way to "send the cursor back" when sending output to the console line?** Alternatively, is there a way to output a "rotating bar" on the console output for the time required to execute a program from point A to point B?

What I'm looking for is to write the following, where each of these lines would appear on the same line in sequence:

```
Processing
Processing .
Processing ..
Pricessing ...
Processing
Processing .
Processing ..
```

Comment: take a look at text_waitbar from the miscellaneous package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can print backspace characters (`\b`) which will move the cursor backwards. Seems like it may overwrite previous characters but on mine it doesn't. So something like this:

```
printf ("processing ");
for i = 1:3
  for i = 1:9
    printf (".");
    pause (0.1);
  endfor
  printf (repmat ("\b", 1, 9));
  printf (repmat (" ", 1, 9));
  printf (repmat ("\b", 1, 9));
endfor
printf ("\n");
```

Alternatively, you can install the Octave Forge [miscellaneous package](https://octave.sourceforge.io/miscellaneous/index.html), there's the `text_waitbar` function:

```
pkg load miscellaneous;

text_waitbar (0, 70); # set length of waitbar
text_waitbar (0.0, "processing ");
for i = 1:3
  for i = 1:9
    text_waitbar (i/9, "processing");
    pause (0.1);
  endfor
endfor
```

which will look like this:

```
[############################################              ]   80%
```

Comment: I was trying to get text_waitbar to work, but this is exactly what I was asking for.

Comment: You were right, I'm impressed at how simple and handy text_waitbar is. The only drawback is the warning for some deprecated syntax in the library.